# Force AVPlayer to only play audio track of audio/video HLS stream

Tags: ios, swift, streaming, avplayer, http-live-streaming

In my app, the user can select between multiple upper bandwidth limits for HLS streams courtesy of AVPlayerItem's preferredPeakBitRate property, but I'd like to add a quality level where only the audio track of the stream is loaded over the network to save bandwidth.

Is it possible to implement audio-only streaming for streams where the video stream is either irrelevant or unwanted by the user without looking at the actual `m3u8` file and finding the audio track myself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use only audio track from video stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317406/use-only-audio-track-from-video-stream)

Comment: It's not. The question you linked is about something entirely different.

Comment: @PeterW. have you found a solution?